# not working: single background image for whole page (header + main content) wordpress

Tags: wordpress, css, background-image

I can't seem to get a single image to appear in the background of the whole page in WordPress, which includes the header, nav bar, and main content page.

For this site: [LHollywood](http://sheiler.info/latin/)

Using a Single-Page Landing child theme of Simone by Mor10.

I can insert a `div class="image"` on the actual page using the WordPress dashboard, and have that appear no problem underneath the nav bar, behind the text boxes ("Latin Hollywood is the ...") .

But I'd like to get the image to be in the background of the header as well.

**The CSS**:

```
.image {
    width: 100%;
    height: 36em; 
    display: block;
    background: url("http://sheiler.info/latin/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/latinh-logo.png") no-repeat center center;
    background-size: cover;
    overflow: visible;
}
```

What I've tried which hasn't worked, all while keeping the name `.image` throughout so that I would not have to change the css:

1. Added `<div class="image">` to the *header.php* file. 
   Note: the original coding in the header.php does not close off the bottom div of -

   div id="content" class="site-content">

Like so:

```
body <?php body_class(); ?>>
div id="page" class="hfeed site">
div class="image">
header id="masthead" class="site-header" role="banner">
a class="skip-link screen-reader-text" href="#content"><?php _e( 'Skip to content', 'simone' ); ?></a>

<?php if ( get_header_image() && ('blank' == get_header_textcolor()) ) { ?>

 <figure class="header-image">
    <a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>" rel="home">
       <img src="<?php header_image(); ?>" width="<?php echo get_custom_header()->width; ?>" height="<?php echo get_custom_header()->height; ?>" alt="">
    </a>
 </figure>
```

etc...

2. Added this in the lander-style.css:

```css
home.page.page-id-16.page-template-default {
    background: url("images/latinh-logo.png") no-repeat center center;
}
```

I also added the class id to other existing divs with no luck.

Comment: did you tried background-image with !important on body?

Answer (score 0):

use this code:

```
body {
background: url("http://sheiler.info/latin/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/latinh-logo.png") no-repeat 50% !important;
background-size: cover;
}
```

be sure not to have any element with background overlapping it (I can see your header has a .site-branding class with background, and there might be more)

Comment: I did tried that on developer tools and GET http://sheiler.info/latin/wp-content/themes/simone/images/latinh-logo.png 404 (Not Found) /latin/wp-content/themes/simone/images/latinh-logo.png:1
GET http://sheiler.info/latin/wp-content/themes/simone/images/latinh-logo.png 404 (Not Found) latinh-logo.png:1   the weirdest thing is that link itself i copy from you and it works but when i put in it does not..but it should.

Comment: I tried developer tools in FF and it works fine, as a matter of fact that's how I tested it. It seems yours isn't reading the http part, but it works fine on my side. You can also upload it to the images folder of your theme and load images/latinh-logo.png and that's it, no http issues

Comment: I commented out all the backgrounds (except for 2 instances where I changed it to background: none;  Then I copied the code Fabio gave above and put it in a) the lander-style.css child style file, nothing. Then I added it into the parent style theme file.  Nothing.  Do I need to go through the parent style and remove all the backgrounds there too, except for the body?

Comment: No it did not work.  So I've switched over to another theme. I didn't think it would be so tricky for me to do something so basic but there it is.  Thanks.